# make VS2012 get the added files of a TFS solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in TFS, i have did GetLatestVersion but all newly added file in TFS was not getting in visual stdio but i can see those added file in TFS Server. Please suggest?

Comment: Are they in the .proj file?

Comment: no, its a normal class file.....

Comment: Should we need to add .csproj file, in order other can get the files in solution

Answer (score 1):

Click on the `Show All Files` in solution explorer to see the newly added file. It will be greyed out. Right click on the file and select `Include` to get it added to your project or soltion.

Common problem is that file will be present in source control but not included into the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

1. File > Source Control > Advanced > Open from Source Control
2. Find you Team Project
3. Open its .proj, .sln file, whichever is appropriate
4. Select 'Yes' / 'Overwrite' if it says you have the same files locally

This will ensure you get all the files from source control, rather than just those in your local project definition.